# Using promise() to run next function doesn't work - PLAIN JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, function, promise

I'm very new to Javascript development.

PROJECT -
I'm currently working on a web chatbot application.

PROBLEM -
I'm not able to use the promise() function to run more than one function one after another.

CODE -

```js
var messages = [
  `Hello name`,
  `I'm hosting a party on Sunday at my house, for my birthday`,
  `I'll be really happy if you'd come`,
];

chatWindow = document.querySelector(".message-day");


const startChat = () => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    messages.forEach((message) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        chatWindow.innerHTML += `
        <div class="message">
            <div class="message-wrapper">
                <div class="message-content">
                 <h6 class="text-dark">Karan</h6>
                 <span>${message}</span>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="message-options">
                 <div class="avatar avatar-sm"><img alt="" src="./assets/media/avatar/6.png"></div>
                  <span class="message-date">9:12am</span> 
            </div>
        </div> `;
      }, 2000);
    });
    resolve();
  });
};

startChat().then(() => {
  console.log("2nd Functions");
});
```

[You can also see the code live here](https://nudlle-testing-server.web.app)

How do I get the **2nd function** to run after the **startchat()**[the first function] ends.

Comment: Please explain the purpose of this function.  Right now, you're looping over an array and setting a bunch of timers all for exactly the same time.  That doesn't appear to make any sense.  Why would you want all the timers to fire at the same time?  And, when exactly do you want the promise to be resolved?  When the last timer is done?

Comment: technically, to run the second function after startChat has completed you'd put the console.log after `startChat()` without waiting for `.then` ... because that's when the command completes ... now, as for the asynchronous code inside startChat, that hasn't even started yet at that stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you return 1 promise for 3 operations but it looks like you meant to make all 3 operations async. To achieve this, you need to return a promise, for each async operation.

You might be looking for something like this:

```js
const messages = [
  `Hello name`,
  `I'm hosting a party on Sunday at my house, for my birthday`,
  `I'll be really happy if you'd come`,
];

const chatWindow = document.querySelector(".message-day");

const startChat = () => messages.map(
    // Returns array of promises wrapping
    // each message into a promise
    (message, index) => new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            chatWindow.innerHTML += `
            <div class="message">
                <div class="message-wrapper">
                    <div class="message-content">
                     <h6 class="text-dark">Karan</h6>
                     <span>${message}</span>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="message-options">
                     <div class="avatar avatar-sm"><img alt="" src="./assets/media/avatar/6.png"></div>
                      <span class="message-date">9:12am</span> 
                </div>
            </div>`;
            resolve(message);
        }, 2000 * index);
    })
);

Promise.all(startChat())
    .then(args => {
        // args will contain same strings as messages
        console.log("2nd Functions", args);
    });
```

If you would like to invoke a callback before/after each message is printed, I'd suggest to pass the callback as an argument to `startChat` & invoke it when needed.

Comment: Thanx man, you really are a rockstar. 
I've started coding in JS from a week ago and I understand that my code was all wrong and muggled up, but even from that, you understood it better than me.